# Android layerlist is not working in different mobiles

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I want to create a drawable file like the below screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

My drawable xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="0px"
        android:left="0px"
        android:right="0px"
        android:bottom="0px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_6sdp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/activeslots"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:left="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:right="@dimen/_58sdp"
        android:bottom="@dimen/_14sdp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <size android:height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:width="@dimen/_20sdp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I created rectangle and oval inside the layer_list. But the issue is it is not working in different mobiles, also the white circle inside the drawable is becomes big after setting height and width.

Comment: If you are looking to set this drawable to radio button, then instead you can set background selector & button selector to Radio button.

Comment: Do you notice in which phones didn't work? Maybe differente API or something?

Comment: Please clarify "...is not working...." That is a bit vague. And as @Juanje mentioned four days ago it would be nice to know which device and which API's have demonstrated this issue.

Comment: its not working in MI A2.android version is oreo

Comment: Is there not other views except Radio button inside the area?

Comment: The way you implemented it, is not best approach. You should manage two drawable, one for background, and one for Radio button.

Comment: please check my updated code above

Comment: height and width of items are hard coded. instead it should change based on the resolution of the screen. so the values must be obtained using dimens.xml. try specifying the right values in dimens.xml for Idpi, Mdpi etc. This should work

Comment: ok i will try to give in dimens.xml file

Comment: the width and height is already from dimens file.